# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 - Using a library?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm using Cocos2D-X, given the following code snippet:

```
CCSwipeGestureRecognizer * swipe = CCSwipeGestureRecognizer::create();
swipe->setTarget(this, callfuncO_selector(GameplayScene::didSwipe));
swipe->setDirection(kSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | kSwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft);
swipe->setCancelsTouchesInView(true);
this->addChild(swipe);
```

I copied the provided CPP and H files over that I was given and they're added to the target. However, for some reason... this line:

```
swipe->setTarget(this, callfuncO_selector(GameplayScene::didSwipe));
```

is giving me issues. I can't even figure out what it's asking me -- let alone what to link for. The header is included and compiled.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "GameplayScene::didSwipe(cocos2d::CCObject*)", referenced from:
      GameplayScene::init() in GameplayScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Commenting out the setTarget line makes everything work fine.

Comment: "I can't even figure out what it's asking me" - Likely neither can we since you didn't bother to put the exact, **full** error message in your question. I have to assume it is `callfuncO_selector` that is missing?

Comment: @WhozCraig I thought the title was all that was relevant -- but I've edited in the full text.

Comment: Never ceases to amaze me how people with no idea what's wrong with their code feel qualified to determine which pieces of information are relevant and which are not!

Comment: Can you post the implementation of your didSwipe(...) method in GameplayScene?

Comment: H: void didSwipe(CCObject * obj);

CPP: void didSwipe(CCObject * obj)
{
    exit(0);
}

Comment: Which version of Cocos2d-x are you using?

Comment: 2.2.1 (the latest stable) I'm using this repository https://github.com/spalx/cocos2d-x-extensions/wiki/CCGestureRecognizer I installed the files by simply downloading the ZIP and dragging them into the project. I set copy and added them to the target.

Comment: I get your error exactly if I comment out the definition (in the .cpp file) for didSwipe(CCObject* object).  Otherwise, it compiles fine.  Stick some goo (e.g. asdfasdf) into your didSwipe function.  Is it actually compiling?

Comment: Sure is. I get "use of undeclared identifier" in the CPP file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44298/discussion-between-nonlinearideas-and-vaughan-hilts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simple** answer here is that the function was not defined properly.  It was defined as:

```
void didSwipe(CCObject* obj)
{
   exit(0);
}
```

It should have been:

```
void GameplayScene::didSwipe(CCObject* obj)
{
   exit(0);
}
```

That is to say, the implementation of the member function of the class and not just a function in the file.

**BUT, and I want to stress this, while this may be the answer to the exact question, I don't think it is the answer to why this was a problem.**

Some kind editor will probably come in and purge this for being off topic, but I'll put it in anyway...

Given:

1. The author did look at this code for some time before seeing it (and I was in chat with him...as it appears at least one other was before me...before it was found).
2. The author posted the API in the comments and it still was not obvious what the problem was.
3. All the people who discussed and looked at the problem are of (reasonably) sound mind, body, and have at least a basic understanding that you actually have to tell the compiler a function is the implementation of a class function and not just a "function".

I think the real answer to this problem was:

1. Don't try to write code after midnight...unless you are naturally nocturnal.
2. Don't try to help people debug their code after midnight...unless you are naturally nocturnal.
3. If the problem doesn't appear obvious in solution after you have looked at it for more than 1 hour, walk away and come back later.
4. Don't feed developers after midnight or they may turn evil.

*Yes, we have all broken these rules.*